# How do I provide a callback when Form.Item has been validated in antd?

Tags: javascript, antd

My Input currently sits within a `<Form>` and `Form.Item`.
I want to trigger a callback only when the validation has been successful, so the callback would not run validation fails.
Is there a way to do that?

```
<Form.Item
  hasFeedback
  name="url"
  rules={[
    {
      required: true,
      min: 5,
      type: "url",
      whitespace: true,
    },
  ]}
  onChange={console.log}
>
  <Input
    name="url"
    onChange={(event) => {
      props.onChange(event);
      setValue(event.target.value);
    }}
  />
</Form.Item>
```

Reference:

- https://ant.design/components/form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by using `Form` component's `onValuesChange` event handler in combination with a `useRef` and the `form.validateFields` instance method. The `useRef` is used to track the previous validation status of the `url` field.

The callback, as currently setup in the example below, will only launch when the field transitions from an error validation state to a successful validation state (which I assume is the behavior you want).

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-launchcallbackonvalidatesuccess-pehue

Happy coding!

P.S. If the `url` `Form.Item` component also has access to the `form` instance, then you should also be able to initiate the same logic using the `Input` component's `onChange` handler.